# Make a scatter plot by drawing 100 items from a mixture distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, mixture-distribution

I was asked the following:

Make a scatter plot by drawing 100 items from a mixture distribution
$0.3 N\left((5, 0)^{T}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.25 \\ 0.25 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}\right)
  +0.7 N\left((-5, 0)^{T}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -0.25 \\ -0.25 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}\right)
  $.

I generate this using the built-in Python random module, specifying the variance and the sample. I got feedback from the instructor

> Mixture distribution combines density functions, not observations.

I have no idea what is wrong? Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: It would help to describe exactly how you generated the values, because it sounds like you did something wrong, such as generating exactly 30 items from the first component and 70 from the second.  Currently we don't have enough information to determine what the problem might be.

Comment: I created to distribution with exact parameters as above, then added them with weights 0.3 and 0.7. Then I used .sample(100) from that distribution.

Comment: It sounds like you will need to consult with the instructor concerning what they meant.

Comment: If you show the plot it is easier to see what you did. The comment from the instructor is not directly clear.

Comment: I guess that you might have drawn two times 100 items, one set of hundred from the first distribution and one set of hundred from the second distribution, and add/sum those two pairwise together with weights 0.3 and 0.7. If that is the case, then you did not use a mixture distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Here you see an example with 400 points

[image: mixture]

---

What you probably did is making weighted sums from pairs of X and Y, ending up with a single cluster of points.